# Element does not get added as a child in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert my elements into a PNG file with HTML2Canvas and later on convert that PNG to PDF. For this i have function:

```
function makeImage(){
    var $printSection = createPrintSection();
    addElement(document.getElementById("accordion"),$printSection);
    addElement(document.getElementById("fullHistory"),$printSection);
    return $printSection;
}
```

where createPrintSection creates div if there's no div named printSection:

```
function createPrintSection(){
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    if (!$printSection){
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    return $printSection;
}
```

Now addelement does:

```
function addElement(elem,parent) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    parent.appendChild(domClone);
}
```

If i put console.log(domClone) after giving it a value it shows that it has successfully done it. However, it will not get added to it's parent children ($printSection - doing console.log($printSection) will return an empty div to console). Any ideas why this might happen?

This is my full code:

```
function tryThis(){
    var $printSection = makeImage();
    console.log($printSection);
    html2canvas($printSection, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {         
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                'image/png');
            console.log(imgData);
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
            var name = document.getElementById("tabelinimi").textContent;
            if (name.length < 2){
                name = "nameless";
            }
            var deit = datemaker();
            var stringB = name+"_table_"+deit+".pdf";
            doc.save(stringB);
        }
    });
    removePrintSection()
}

function makeImage(){
    var printSection = createPrintSection();
    console.log(printSection);
    addElement(document.getElementById("accordion"),printSection);
    addElement(document.getElementById("fullHistory"),printSection);
    return printSection;
}

function datemaker(){
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    today = mm+'.'+dd+'.'+yyyy;
    return today;
}

function createPrintSection(){
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    if (!$printSection){
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    return $printSection;
}

function addElement(elem,parent) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    domClone.id = elem.id+"_copy";
    console.log("DomClone: ");
    console.log(domClone);
    parent.appendChild(domClone);
    console.log("Parent: ");
    console.log(parent);
}

function removePrintSection(){
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    if (!$printSection){
        return;
    }
    else{
        $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

This is an image snippet from console:

[image]

I call out tryThis() with a button click from HTML.

Comment: A problem you could have by cloning elements. Once you clone them you will have multiple elements with the same ID. ID's should be unique...

Comment: I added:
domClone.id = elem.id+"_copy";

Still no results..

Comment: I didn't look for the problem of it not working. I just noticed an issue you could face by using cloneNode.Can you recreate the problem using http://jsfiddle.net/ It will be easier to debug and find the problem you face. Thank you.

Comment: There is no problem in your js, maybe something to do with HTML, as asked by @NewToJS, a fiddle or a sample of your markup in order to reproduce the issue will help us help you.

Comment: I tried to do jsfiddle, apparently it worked there aswell with code given here.
http://jsfiddle.net/vgb0jtm9/ I must go deeper to search this problem..

Comment: Double check you are linking the page to the jQuery library, it's a very easy mistake to make. Also open your browsers console to check for any errors. It must be something really simple if you can get it working on jsfiddle but not locally or on the host you're using.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that if i put console.log in front of parent.appendChild() and after it with: console.log(domClone) and after it console.log(parent) then i will get the cloned element, accordion and i will get the parent which does not have the cloned element added..

Comment: are you sure you don't call `createPrintSection()` again? this will clear its innerHTML

Comment: It's called only once, i'll edit my original post

Comment: Added my whole code + image snippet from console, maybe this will help

Comment: Instead of `document.body.appendChild` try `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild`.

Comment: Apparently as @NewToJS pointed out, the mistake was in tryThis(). removePrintSection() command was triggered before makeImage finished rendering the image, thus having no image to process.